# Demo for Displaying Multiple Google Directions (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, demo, directions

Hey all, is there a functioning demo out there for displaying multiple directions routes on a single Google map? [The other question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537676/google-maps-directions-v3-multiple-directions-on-a-map) links to a set of snippets…I feel like I'd be able to work better I just saw a functional script in action.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the snippets from the other post, I got what I wanted. Not only did I achieve multiple directions displays on the same map, but there are also unique waypoints to each directions object.

[Link to the demo](http://joshdcompton.com/google_maps/mult_directions/test.html)